# Map returns Empty statement array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, array.prototype.map

I have this function

```
function getDaysArray(days: number): number[] {
        return [...new Array(days)].map((_x, i) => {
            return i + 1;
        });
}
```

which is supposed to return an array of days by month,
so for example If I log `getDaysArray(31)` I expect to have an array like this

```
[1,2,...,31]
```

but instead, I am getting this:

```
[empty × 31]
```

Does anyone know what is happening?

Comment: I cannot reproduce. This output is only expected if you do `new Array(days).map(…)`, without array spread syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this

```js
function getDaysArray(days) {
        return Array.from({length: days}).map((_, i) => i + 1)

}

console.log(getDaysArray(31))
```

Answer (score -1):

`Array.from({length:10},(_,i)=>i+1);`

```js
function getDaysArray(days: number): number[] {
        return Array.from({length:days},(_,i)=>i+1);
}
```

```js
function getDaysArray(days) {
        return Array.from({length:days},(_,i)=>i+1);
}

console.log(getDaysArray(31));
```